# Alternative way of joining two datasets in SAS

Tags: join, sas

I have two datasets `DS1` and `DS2`.  `DS1` is 100,000rows x 40cols, `DS2` is 20,000rows x 20cols. I actually need to pull `COL1` from `DS1` if some fields match `DS2`.
Since I am very-very new to SAS, I am trying to stick to SQL logic.

So basically I did (shot version)

```
proc sql;
...
SELECT DS1.col1 
FROM DS1 INNER JOIN DS2 
on DS1.COL2=DS2.COL3 
OR DS1.COL3=DS2.COL3 
OR DS1.COL4=DS2.COL2
...
```

After an hour or so, it was still running, but I was getting emails from SAS that I am using 700gb or so. Is there a better and faster SAS-way of doing this operation?

Comment: Your join condition seems strange...you're looking for any column in table 1 that matches any column in table 2?

Comment: Well, I have 1 column in DS1 and multiple columns in DS2 that might match that one column in DS1

Comment: Then perhaps you are incorrectly referencing col3/col4 in DS1 in your join condition?

Comment: I think your problem is it's doing a cartesian join.  So it has to create a table that is (100,000)*(20,000)*(60) in size, which is pretty big.  120 billion  cells times 8 bytes per cell means almost a terabyte of space needed to compute the cartesian product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use 3 separate queries and use a `UNION`

```
proc sql;
...
SELECT DS1.col1 
FROM DS1 INNER JOIN DS2 
on DS1.COL2=DS2.COL3 

UNION

SELECT DS1.col1 
FROM DS1 INNER JOIN DS2 
On DS1.COL3=DS2.COL3 

UNION

SELECT DS1.col1 
FROM DS1 INNER JOIN DS2 
ON DS1.COL4=DS2.COL2
...
```

Comment: Will that avoid a cartesian join?

Comment: I actually ended up using IN clause for each column and UNIONed them all together. @Robert gave me a good idea to add filters (check for nulls etc.) It executes fast now.

Comment: @Joe Yes, it will remove the cartesian join.  It is explicitly doing 3 inner joins, and then getting the distinct values from each.

Answer (score 3):

You may have null or blank values in the columns you are joining on.  Your query is probably matching all the null/blank columns together resulting in a very large result set.

I suggest adding additional clauses to exclude null results.

Also - if the same row happens to exist in both tables, then you should also prevent the row from joining to itself.

Either of these could effectively result in a cartesian product join (or something close to a cartesian product join).

**EDIT :** By the way - a good way of debugging this type of problem is to limit both datasets to a certain number of rows - say 100 in each - and then running it and checking the output to make sure it's expected.  You can do this using the SQL options `inobs=`, `outobs=`, and `loops=`.  [Here's a link to the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/62086/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001360938.htm).

Comment: Yes, I used your advise as well and used LENGTH(field)>3 checks. That helped to speedup the query. Unfortunately I can't pick TWO correct answers. Voteup!

Answer (score 0):

First sort the datasets that you are trying to merge using proc sort. Then merge the datasets based on id.

Here is how you can do it.
 I have assumed you match field as ID

```
proc sort data=DS1;
by ID;
proc sort data=DS2;
by ID;

data out;
merge DS1 DS2;
by ID;
run;
```

You can use proc sort for Ds3 and DS4 and then include them in merge statement if you need to join them as well.